# Regex how to replace part of a string with another

Tags: java, javascript, regex, notepad++

I need to replace part of a text with some other string.

Example:

```
{abc,bcd},{ def,ghi}
```

I want to replace `abc` and `def` to `x:abc` and `x:def`.

I want to replace the first value in the opening braces.
But I wont know what value I will get.

So in order to replace i need to identify the letter after the opening braces, which I am able to identify by using this pattern `/\{.*?\,/`

But I dont now how do I replace the matched string with the text. How do i do it?

The answer need not be relevant to notepad++ . You can use any language to explain how to do it.

Comment: what you want is still a little ambiguous...

Comment: Do you want to remove the space(s) before `def` or not?

Comment: @M42: space is not an issue. Kent's answer is alright. But I want to change the value abc to "abc". SO i am working on that. Thanks

Comment: So, you want to add double quote arround abc or def?

Comment: @M42: Both. As i said there may be many texts like that. Which comes just after the open braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, to add double quote arround abc or def:

Search what: `\{\s*(\w+)`
Replace with: `{x:"$1"`

this will change `{abc,bcd},{ def,ghi}` to `{x:"abc",bcd},{x:"def",ghi}`

Or if it can be any char but comma after the brace:

Search what: `\{([^,]+)`
Replace with: `{x:"$1"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need regex to do it.

find:

```
{
```

replace it with:

```
{"x":
```

test in terminal, sed uses `BRE`, so `{` doesn't have special meaning.

```
kent$ echo "{abc,bcd},{ def,ghi}"|sed 's/{/{"x":/g'
{"x":abc,bcd},{"x": def,ghi}
```